# Compare Text Across Row A in Both Sheets and Add if not found

Tags: excel, vba

VBA is not finding the matching date in Monthly2. This code is finding all dates that contain 2021 in Sheet1, and pasting them into the correct range, except it is not finding the duplicate date.

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AD1")
Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Monthly2").Range("A1:AD1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Monthly2")

For Each celldate In rng1

CellValue = celldate

    If CellValue Like "*2021*" Then
       
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly2")
            
            LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Address
                   
            ColumnLetterM = Split(LastColumn, "$")(1)
            
            Set valFound = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly2").Range("A1:AD1").Cells.Find(CellValue)
              
            End With

          If valFound Is Nothing Then
          
          Sheets("Monthly2").Range(ColumnLetterM & "1").Value = celldate
          
                                                 
           Else
                                                        
           End If
            
        End If
    
Next celldate

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cell values you're checking actual dates, or dates stored as text?

Comment: If they're actual dates then you need something like `Year(celldate.Value) = 2021`

Comment: It is finding the last date with 2021 in Sheet1 and it is pasting into all cells within the range of Monthly2. I want it to paste, and loop to next date. but its finding only the last date, and pasting into all cells in the range.

Comment: One problem is `LastColumn = Cells` inside `With` block should be `.Cells` with a dot. I think there may be more problems though with the Inner loop. My guess is you should wait until the loop ends before pasting the date into the last column if no match found.

Comment: @CDP1802 The lastcolumn formula works. I can't get it to find the date that's already there and go to the next date that was found to compare.

Comment: Currently it finds the last column and fills in the following cells with the dates from Sheet1.

Comment: What column is the last column before the macro runs ?

Comment: When the sheet is empty the first column available is B, but once the macro runs, the dates from sheet1 fill what is expected, and then the next available column is M

Comment: So it's recognizing the last column to fill in, but it's not comparing dates already on Monthly2 to avoid duplication.

Comment: What did you mean by **dates that started as text but the date format has changed the sequence**. Give an example of a date value that is being duplicated

Comment: date is in the cell as 3/28/2021.  Again the problem is not the format of the text, because it's finding it just fine.  It's comparing the date from the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Monthly2()
    Dim celldate As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, v, m
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AD1")
    Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Monthly2").Range("A1:AD1")
    
    For Each celldate In rng1.Cells
        v = celldate.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            If Year(v) = 2021 Then
                m = Application.Match(CLng(v), rng2, 0) 'match in rng2?
                If IsError(m) Then
                    'copy date to next empty cell on row1 on Monthly2
                    rng2.Parent.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = v
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next celldate
End Sub
```

Comment: my problem isn't finding 2021, my problem is finding the first cell with 2021, and then pasting it into the first available cell into Monthly2 if not found, then looping to the next found date of 2021 in Sheet1, and repeating until no more dates found in Sheet1 with 2021.

Comment: Yeah didn't work for me. But looked at my edited code above. I have been able to copy the dates found into the date range in Monthly2, but it's not recognizing that either 1) It has already looped through the dates or 2) it's not finding the matching date it just pasted into Monthly2

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with date formats. This script logs the result of each comparison so hopefully will identify the problem.

```vb
Sub debugging()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lastcol As Integer
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, bFound As Boolean

    ' log file
    Dim fso, ts
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.createtextfile("debug.log")

    ' rng1
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastcol = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, lastcol)

    ' rng2
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Monthly2")
    lastcol = ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1").Resize(1, lastcol)

    ts.writeline "rng1 = " & rng1.Address
    ts.writeline "rng2 = " & rng2.Address

    ' compare ws1 to ws2
    For Each cell1 In rng1

       ts.writeline vbCr & "ws1 " & cell1.Address & " is '" & cell1.Value & "' " & cell1.NumberFormat
       If cell1.Value Like "*2021" Then

           bFound = False
           For Each cell2 In rng2
               If cell1 = cell2 Then
                   ts.writeline "  ws2 " & cell2.Address & " '" & cell2.Value & "' = FOUND"
                   bFound = True
                   Exit For
               Else
                   ts.writeline "  ws2 " & cell2.Address & " '" & cell2.Value & "' <>"
               End If
           Next
    
           ' not found so add column
           If bFound = False Then
               lastcol = lastcol + 1
               ws2.Cells(1, lastcol).Value2 = cell1
               Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1").Resize(1, lastcol)
               ts.writeline cell1 & " added rng2 now " & rng2.Address
           End If
       Else
           ts.writeline "SKIPPED Not like *2021*"
       End If

    Next
    
    ts.Close
    MsgBox "See debug.log"
End Sub
```